# Display image from url to gridview in fragments

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, universal-image-loader

```
extends SherlockFragment{
```

I am developing application using sherlock fragments and sliding menu., and in my first frament layout i have to show grid view with images from url., i have decided to use [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

and I can get the json and all values., but while setting the adapter to grid view in the ImageAdapter class i am getting NULL Pointer exception.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.videos_layout, container,
            false);
    this.setRetainInstance(true);
    gridView = (GridView) v.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
     imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    return v;

}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

int i = 0;
    for (HashMap<String, String> map : VideoItems) {
        imageUrls[i] = map.get(TAG_THUMNAIL);
        System.out.println(imageUrls[i]);
        i++;

    }
    defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().cacheInMemory()
            .cacheOnDisc().build();

    config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getActivity()
            .getApplicationContext()).defaultDisplayImageOptions(
            defaultOptions).build();
     imageLoader.init(config);
    gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getActivity()));
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
        }
    });
    this.gridView.setOnScrollListener(new PauseOnScrollListener(
            imageLoader, true, true));
}

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    public ImageAdapter(Context ctx){
        mContext=ctx;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return imageUrls.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    public class ViewHolder{
        ImageView imageView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder=new ViewHolder();
        Log.v("hi", "hhdsjf");
        if (convertView == null) {
               convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(
                        R.layout.video_layout_item, parent, false);
            holder.imageView= (ImageView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.image);

            convertView.setTag(holder);

            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
        try {
            imageLoader.displayImage(imageUrls[position], holder.imageView, defaultOptions);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return convertView;
    }
}
```

> LOG Cat error:

```
03-12 15:37:47.164: E/AndroidRuntime(9671): java.lang.NullPointerException
```

03-12 15:37:47.164: E/AndroidRuntime(9671):     at com.slidingmenu.example.fragments.VideosFragment.onActivityCreated(VideosFragment.java:112)
03-12 15:37:47.164: E/AndroidRuntime(9671):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:891)
03-12 15:37:47.164: E/AndroidRuntime(9671):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1080)
03-12 15:37:47.164: E/AndroidRuntime(9671):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:622)
03-12 15:37:47.164: E/AndroidRuntime(9671):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1416)
03-12 15:37:47.164: E/AndroidRuntime(9671):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:420)
03-12 15:37:47.164: E/AndroidRuntime(9671):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
03-12 15:37:47.164: E/AndroidRuntime(9671):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-12 15:37:47.164: E/AndroidRuntime(9671):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
03-12 15:37:47.164: E/AndroidRuntime(9671):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
03-12 15:37:47.164: E/AndroidRuntime(9671):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-12 15:37:47.164: E/AndroidRuntime(9671):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-12 15:37:47.164: E/AndroidRuntime(9671):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
03-12 15:37:47.164: E/AndroidRuntime(9671):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
03-12 15:37:47.164: E/AndroidRuntime(9671):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

> i couldn't find where i missed to initialize something.,
>   Thanks in advance.,

Comment: this.gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getActivity()));

this is my 112 line., what is wrong with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

1.Caching is NOT enabled by default. If you want loaded images will be cached in memory and/or on disc then you should enable caching in DisplayImageOptions this way:

```
DisplayImageOptions defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
    .cacheInMemory()
    .cacheOnDisc()
    .build();

ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
         .defaultDisplayImageOptions(defaultOptions)
         .build();
ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
```

Change this in your Adapter..

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;

public ImageAdapter(Context ctx) {
    mContext = ctx;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return imageUrls.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
public class ViewHolder {

    ImageView imageView;

}

if (convertView == null) {
   convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(
            R.layout.video_layout_item, parent, false);
holder.imageView= (ImageView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.imageViewid);

convertView.setTag(holder);

} else {
    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
}

  try {
imageLoader.displayImage(imageUrls[position], holder.imageView, defaultOptions);

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

return convertView;
```

}
Try this to set Adapter

```
ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
            gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: i have updated my code but it doesn't work., still null pointer exception; what i am doing wrong?

Comment: it gives error in these lines only

gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getActivity()));

it doesn't call that class.,

Comment: i have placed the full code., 
gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getActivity()));
for this line i am getting always nullpointer., how it is possible. isn't wrong statement?